# Swift Get Fragment in url

Tags: swift

I need to take specific fragment in url

```
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print(webView.url?.fragment)            
    }
```

In webView Delegate i check the url when page finish loading , if in the url i find the fragment , in my case #access_token , i want save it and close the Web page .

For the moment i can only do this print(webView.url?.fragment) but print all the fragment , i want ONLY #access_token .

exaple url :

https://example.com/oauth-callback#access_token=<TOKEN_NUMBER>&scope=....

Comment: The problem really is that this is an improper fragment (#). It should have been a query (?). Then parsing it would be easy.

Comment: Matt's very valid point accepted, are you saying you want to detect if `#access_token` is in the url, and then save the token number after it?

Comment: i want  if #access_token is in the url and then save the token number after it

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to get the fragment , i use Regex of type ECMAScript.

```
            let fragment: String? = webView.url?.fragment
        
        if ((fragment?.contains("access_token")) != nil) {
            let pattern = #"access_token=(.*)&scope"#
            let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
            let testString = fragment
            
            let stringRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: testString!.utf16.count)
            let matches = regex.matches(in: testString!, range: stringRange)
            var result: [[String]] = []
            for match in matches {
                var groups: [String] = []
                for rangeIndex in 1 ..< match.numberOfRanges {
                    let nsRange = match.range(at: rangeIndex)
                    guard !NSEqualRanges(nsRange, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0)) else { continue }
                    let string = (testString! as NSString).substring(with: nsRange)
                    groups.append(string)
                }
                if !groups.isEmpty {
                    result.append(groups)
                }
            }
            let token = result.first
            print(token as Any)
        }
```

Comment: You seem to be making hard work of this, and not taking advantage of some of the newer APIs.  Will there ever be more than one token in the string?